# rspec controller test instance variable calls method

Tags: rspec, controller, activeadmin, instance-variables

I'm trying to write a test for an ActiveAdmin controller that I inherited and I'm having trouble checking that an instance variable is calling a method. The behavior that I want is a side effect of calling the method so I would like to ensure that it's called.

Here's the controller:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    before_filter :get_user

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by_login(params[:id])
      if !@user
        flash[:notice] = "No user found with that login"
        return false
      end
    end

  end
  member_action :tos_ban, :method => :post do
    @user.ban!(current_user, "admin ban", 1)
    flash[:notice] = "#{@user.display_name} successfully TOS Banned"
    redirect_back
  end
end
```

And, my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ActiveAdmin::UsersController do
  render_views
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin => admin) }
  let(:administrator) { FactoryGirl.create(:administrator) }
  let(:banned_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before(:each) do
    login_as(user)
    session[:last_admin_action_time] = Time.now
    session[:current_admin_id] = administrator.id
 end

  describe 'banning users' do
    context 'as an administrator' do
      let(:admin) { true }

      before(:each) do
        User.should_receive(:ban!).once           # I want something like this
                                                  # on @user in the controller
        post :tos_ban, :id => banned_user.login
      end

      it 'bans the right user' do
        assigns(:user).should eq(banned_user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

So, after a little RTFMing -- via the RSpec Book -- I figured out that I need to be using mocks:

```
it 'bans the user' do
  banned_user = mock_model(User)
  User.stub(:find_by_login).and_return(banned_user)
  banned_user.should_receive(:ban!)
  banned_user.should_receive(:display_name)
  post :tos_ban, :id => banned_user.login
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`banned_user.should_receive(:ban!)`

In your controller you assign a reference of the record (an instance of User) to your instance variable. You want to refer to that instance (not the User object nor the variable) to make your assertions.